# In Dropwizard the admin and application would be on the same port

Tags: java, configuration, dropwizard

I want to configure my dropwizard application. I want that the admin page and the application page will be on the same port.

I found the default server setup

```
server:
  type: simple
  applicationContextPath: /application
  adminContextPath: /admin
  connector:
    type: http
    port: 8080
```

This is working. But I want to open an other port for https. I have tried with default server, but it does not support the admin and the applicatio would be available on the same port.

Have you got any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it by adding a new subsection of type `https`. For more detail, see http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/core.html#ssl